# The Line integral parametrization

Tags: calculus

I need to find:$\int_{\gamma}xdx+(x+y)dy+(x+y+z)dz$

then$\gamma$ is the intersection between $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and $z=x+y$

I solved it by the following parametrization:
$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x(t)=cost\\ 
y(t)=sint\\
0\leq t\leq 2\pi
\end{matrix}\right.$

Does it right? I not sure cause the intersection of 2 of these surfaces it's ellipse...

Thanks!

Comment: It is in fact an ellipse, but you haven't said what $z(t)$ is!

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin, thanks. $z(t)=cost+sint$, but if it's ellipse should I to multiply $cost$ by $a$ and $sint$ by $b$?

Comment: No, no. The parametrization is what you have. It's an ellipse in a tilted plane, but it projects to the unit circle in the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do your problem by using [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem). Let $$S: z=x+y, (x,y)\in D$$ where $D: x^2+y^2\le a^2$. During the way we satisfy the theorem we face to the following normal vector $n$: $$n=\pm\frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f||}$$ wherein $f=x+y-z$ here. So we have $$n=\pm\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$$ We consider $n$ to be upward so we take the "$-$" sign of above. Moreover, $$d\sigma=\frac{||\nabla f||}{|\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}|}dxdy=\sqrt{3}dxdy$$ (Try to find it by yourself!) According to the definition $$\textbf{Curl}(F)=\begin{vmatrix}
  \textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k}\\
  \frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\\
  x &x+y &x+y+z
\end{vmatrix}=(1,-1,1)$$ So, finally, $$\oint\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}=\iint_{(S)}\textbf{Curl}(F)\cdot\textbf{n}d\sigma=...=\iint_D dxdy=\pi a^2$$

[image]

Comment: $^++1+^+\quad \ddot\smile$